# Unmarshal List to Types

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have this xml

```
<data-set>
    <list-property name="columns">...</list-property>
    <list-property name="resultSet">...</list-property>
<data-set>
```

Need to unmarshal this to object:

```
public class DataSet {

    private Columns columns;

    private ResultSet resultSet;
    ...
}
```

Help me to implement that if it possible.

**Update**
What I tried to do:

```
public class DataSet {

    @XmlElement("list-property")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DataSetListPropertyAdapter.class)
    private Columns columns;

    @XmlElement("list-property")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DataSetListPropertyAdapter.class)
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    ...
}

public class DataSetListPropertyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ListProperty, ListProperty> {
@Override
public ListProperty unmarshal(ListProperty v) throws Exception {
    ListProperty listProperty;
    switch (v.getName()) {
        case "columns":
            listProperty = new Columns();
            break;
        case "resultSet":
            listProperty = new ResultSet();
            break;
        default:
            listProperty = new ListProperty();
    }
    listProperty.setStructure(v.getStructure());
    return listProperty;
}

    @Override
    public ListProperty marshal(ListProperty v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }
}

public class Columns extends ListProperty {
public Columns() {
    name = "columns";
}
}

public class ListProperty extends NamedElement implements PropertyType{

@XmlElement(name = "structure")
private List<Structure> structure = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlTransient
public class NamedElement {

@XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
protected String name;
}
```

When go unmarshalling then only first element of annotated objects parsed. Another is null. When I comment first then second becames parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think what you're trying to do is possible with JAXB reference implementation.

However, if you can change implementation, EclipseLink MOXy offer the @XmlPath that should resolve your problem :

```
public class DataSet {

    @XmlPath("node[@name='columns']")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DataSetListPropertyAdapter.class)
    private Columns columns;

    @XmlPath("node[@name='resultSet']")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DataSetListPropertyAdapter.class)
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    ...
}
```

More on @XmlPath : http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/advanced_concepts005.htm

Comment: Thx for your response. I think it is what i need. But I tried to install MOXy and didn't have success. The WebSphere App container what I use already has JAXB Provider. How can I use it. I tried to change classloader options to PARENT_LAST but then had error com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype. WebSphere 8.5.5.11

Comment: Did you follow the following instructions : http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/websphere.htm ?

Comment: I think it should be another question. Thx